# I can't get "Typechain" folder when I install dependencies using hardhat

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependencies, solidity, hardhat

When I install all the dependencies but didn't get the "typechain" folder in the typescript hardhat. how to get it?

npm init

npm install --save-dev hardhat

npx hardaht

Select an Advance sample project ....

npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.8.2" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@^2.0.0" "ethereum-waffle@^3.0.0" "chai@^4.2.0" "ethers@^5.0.0" "solhint@^3.3.6" "solidity- coverage@^0.7.16" "@typechain/ethers-v5@^7.0.1" "@typechain/hardhat@^2.3.0" "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.29.1" "@typescript-eslint/parser@^4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Run `npx hardhat compile` to generate the typechain folder when using hardhat with solidity

As seen in the "Tasks" section of https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typechain/hardhat/v/3.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after deleting the the typechain folder

be sure to run the following command before running `npx hardhat compile`:

`npx hardhat clean` or in my case `yarn hardhat clean`

from the documentation

> Warning: before running it for the first time you need to do `hardhat clean`, otherwise TypeChain will think that there is no need to generate any typings.

https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain/tree/master/packages/hardhat